# Trying to get property of non-object using php and react

Tags: php, reactjs

I have an issue with php I always get **trying to get property of non-object** error when I try to make a post request with react.
This is my php code.

**create.php**

```
<?php 
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");

include_once '../config/database.php';
include_once '../class/product.php';

$database = new Database();
$db = $database->getConnection();

$item = new Product($db);

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));


$item->name = $data->name;
$item->price = $data->price;

if ($item->createProduct()) {
    echo json_encode("Product created.");
} else {
    echo json_encode("Failed to create product.");
} ?>
```

**product.php**

```
// POST request to create a product.
    public function createProduct() {
        $sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO 
                    ". $this->db_table ."
                SET
                    name = :name,
                    price = :price,


        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sqlQuery);
        
        // sanitize data

        $this->name=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->name));
        $this->price=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->price));

        // bind data

        $stmt->bindParam(":name", $this->name);
        $stmt->bindParam(":price", $this->price);
    
        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

and this react function responsible for making the request after creating a product array with a form.

**react.js**

```
const onSubmit = (event) => {
    
    const product = {
        name: state.name,
        price: state.price,
    }

    console.log(product)

    axios.post('http://localhost:8080/api/create.php', product)
        .then(response => {
            if (response.data) {
                setProducts([...products, product])
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        })
```

}

I hope it's clear, I appreciate help!

Comment: What do you get if you `var_dump($data);`?

Comment: Also check  `file_get_contents("php://input")` and https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php.

Comment: array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#4 (9) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["name"]=>
    string(2) "QS"
    ["price"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
}

Comment: I'm not familiar with `php://input` but I think it is easier to use `$_POST` super global to access request data maybe.

Comment: Looks like $data is an array with a single object, so `$data[0]->property`

Comment: unfortunately, it does not work, I got another error Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass